# 2 Line Chart with different labels | Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Im trying to plot 2 dataset into 1 line chart dataset. I have convert the date and the value but i want to continue the second dataset with the first one. Heres what i've done.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <canvas id="lineChart" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
            <script>
              var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d")
              var lineChart = new Chart(ctx,{
                type : 'line',
                data: {
                  labels : {{ tanggal|safe }},
                  datasets: [
                    {
                        label:"Terkonfirmasi",
                        data: {{ terkonfirmasi | safe }},
                        fill : false,
                        borderColor: "rgb(75,192,192)",
                        lineTension:0.1
                    },
                    {
                        labels:{{tanggal_predict|safe}},
                        label:"Prediksi",
                        data: {{ predicted_cases|safe}},
                        fill : false,
                        borderColor: "rgb(192,0,0)",
                        lineTension:0.1
                  }
                ]
                },
                options:{
                  responsive:false
                }
              });
            </script>
          </div>
```

here is the result

[image: result]

and this is what i expected

[image]

the 'tanggal_predict' list is contained the date of predicted value only

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to fill your data array of your red line with the amount of null values until it hits the right spot, alternatively you can supply your data array containing objects where you can specify the x and y value so you can put it directly where you want

Comment: i tried adding None to the array but the result is None is not defined in flask. It went well in notebook tho

Answer (score 0):

I made it with adding 'null' to the array , even tho in python it is None but in javascript it is null. So i added a string 'null' to the array and i got the result i wanted
[image]